# LinkedBlockingQueue failing to wait for the threads to execute

Tags: java, multithreading

I am making a WordCounter, which has several threads counting the words in different files. I have gotten everything to work, except one little issue.

I cannot figure out a proper way to wait for the threads to finish. Everything works if I set a Thread.sleep to wait for a short amount of time, the only problem is that, this will not be a proper solution if the counter takes longer than the sleep does.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class WordCounter implements Runnable{
    private String file;
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> q;
    private int words = 0;

    public WordCounter(String f, BlockingQueue<Integer> queue){
        file = f;
        q = queue;
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(file));

            while (in.hasNext()){
                in.next();
                words++;
            }
            in.close();
            System.out.println(file + ": " + words);
            q.add(words);
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(file + " blev ikke fundet.");
        }
    }

}
```

This is the code from the actual word-counter. I want my main-thread to wait for these word-counter threads to do the q.add(words); function before doing anything else.

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class MainThread implements Runnable{

    private String[] arguments;

    public MainThread(String[] args){
        arguments = args;
    }

    public void run() {

        final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();

        for(String f : arguments){
            WordCounter c = new WordCounter(f, queue);
            Thread t = new Thread(c);
            t.start();  
        }
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            try {
                System.out.println(queue.take());
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the main-thread. I will need some sort of way to wait for the other threads to finish before I continue to my while statement at the bottom, but how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ExecutorService and wait on the Future returned.  The code below will submit each task to a thread within the executor service (thread pool) and get back the future for that task.  When all submitted it will wait on the future.  The get method will only return when the `run` method completes in the task.

```
public class MainThread implements Runnable{

    private String[] arguments;

    public MainThread(String[] args){
        arguments = args;
    }

    public void run() {

        ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(arguments.length);
        final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();
        List<Future<?>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String f : arguments){
            tasks.add(e.submit(new WordCounter(f, queue)));
        }
        for(Future<?> f : tasks) {
            f.get();
        }
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            try {
                System.out.println(queue.take());
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## However

You can make your code cleaner by removing the BlockingQueue entirely and having each task be a `Callable<Integer>` where it simply returns the `words` variable.  And when you call `future.get()` the return value there would be the word count.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do:

1. create a counter variable (here is how to do it in a way that is safe for [multi-threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html)) to keep track of how many threads you are spawning in the main
   thread
2. create an interface with function signatures to
   increment/decrement that counter
3. implement that interface in your
   main thread
4. subclass a worker thread to accept that interface as
   a parameter
5. once the worker thread finishes, call that interface
   to decrement the number of running threads.
6. in the implementation of the decrement function on the main thread, add a
   condition to do something once the counter is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the created threads in a list and join them from the current thread.
Something like this:

```
List<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<Thread>();

for (String f : arguments) {
  WordCounter c = new WordCounter(f, queue);
  Thread t = new Thread(c);
  t.start();
  threads.add(t);
}

for (Thread t : threads) {
  t.join();
}
```

The `join()` method will block until the thread terminates.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many threads to wait on, then you can use a shared [semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).  The worker threads each calls `release` on the semaphore when they're done; the main thread calls `acquire(n)` where `n` is the number of worker threads, which causes the main thread to wait until `n` permits are available (i.e. until all `n` worker threads are finished).

Comment: That's a great way to handle this - I didn't know about the Semaphore class! the only thing is that you're required to know exactly how many threads is spawned right away.